# MYSQL query for selecting only most recent data row set with expired dates

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

From the following sample data set I'm trying to get only the most recent policy information (auto, home and life) for clients who have expired policies.

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| record_id | client_id | policy_type | expiration_date |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
|       001 |       001 | auto        | 2019-05-06      |
|       002 |       001 | home        | 2019-05-06      |
|       003 |       001 | life        | 2019-05-06      |
|       004 |       002 | auto        | 2019-07-22      |
|       005 |       002 | home        | 2019-07-22      |
|       006 |       002 | life        | 2019-07-22      |
|       007 |       001 | auto        | 2020-01-20      |
|       008 |       001 | home        | 2020-01-20      |
|       009 |       001 | life        | 2020-01-20      |
|       010 |       003 | auto        | 2019-07-23      |
|       011 |       003 | home        | 2019-07-23      |
|       012 |       003 | life        | 2019-07-23      |
|       013 |       004 | auto        | 2019-01-30      |
|       014 |       004 | home        | 2019-01-30      |
|       015 |       004 | life        | 2019-01-30      |
|       016 |       002 | auto        | 2020-04-11      |
|       017 |       002 | home        | 2020-04-11      |
|       018 |       002 | life        | 2020-04-11      |
|       019 |       003 | auto        | 2020-06-17      |
|       020 |       003 | home        | 2020-06-17      |
|       021 |       003 | life        | 2020-06-17      |
|       022 |       004 | auto        | 2020-02-01      |
|       023 |       004 | home        | 2020-02-01      |
|       024 |       004 | life        | 2020-02-01      |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

If anyone can help with the query statement I will much appreciate it.

Thanks,
Raffi

Comment: what's your DBMS version?

Answer (score 1):

For DBMS version 8+, you can use an analytic function such as `dense_rank()`

```
SELECT record_id, client_id, policy_type, expiration_date 
  FROM
 (
  SELECT t.*,
         dense_rank() over (partition by client_id, policy_type order by expiration_date desc) as dr 
    FROM tab t
) tt
WHERE dr = 1;
```

By the above one, grouping is handled through `partition by` and the latest date derived through `order by` clause after filtering out by returning values of `1` from the analytic function

For all versions (especially prior to 8), the following statement might be used

```
SELECT t1.record_id, t1.client_id, t1.policy_type, t1.expiration_date 
  FROM tab t1
  JOIN
      (
       SELECT max(expiration_date) AS expiration_date, policy_type 
         FROM tab
        GROUP BY client_id, policy_type
       ) t2
    ON t2.expiration_date=t1.expiration_date AND t2.policy_type = t1.policy_type;
```

*Considering your comment that tells the results should be for each client, I added `client_id` column to the `partition by` list of the first query, and `GROUP BY` list of the second query.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0194013aa603ac1560f956b1b90dc406)</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I need to do this in mysql.

Comment: @Raffi . . . Yeah.  So.  Both these queries should work in MySQL.

Comment: The first query results in a syntax error and the second gives the following result.

+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+<br>
| record_id | client_id | policy_type | expiration_date |<br>
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+<br>
| 19        | 3         | auto        | 2020-06-17      |<br>
| 20        | 3         | home        | 2020-06-17      |<br>
| 21        | 3         | life        | 2020-06-17      |<br>
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+<br>

Comment: The desired query result for the sample data set would be record_id 7,8,9,22,23,24.

Also, there can be multiple expired policies for each client. Only the most recent expired policy set (auto,home,life) should be selected for clients whose policies are expired (expiration_date is earlier than today's date).

Thanks,
Raffi

Comment: I deliberately asked about the version whether 8+ or 8-, since analytic functions do not work for version 8-. As a result, your version seems to be 8- @Raffi